# Cannot create a virtual enviroment with Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python

When I type the command sudo python3 -m venv venv001 I get this error:

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv package using the following command.

    apt install python3.8-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/mike/venv001/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

so, I try sudo apt install python3.8-env and get the error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8-venv : Depends: python3.8 (= 3.8.2-1ubuntu1) but 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried a couple of the sudo apt install -f, or --fix- commands, but still can't seem to recover from these errors.

Comment: Are you using a custom PPA?  `python3.8` that is present in your system is *not* the version of Python 3.8 that ships with Ubuntu (we know this because of the `-0ubuntu1~20.04` name at the end of it.  Have you done `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` ever to get the latest updates for your system/

Answer (score 0):

You can install python3 virtual environment with below command

```
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```

Later you can create the virtual environment with below command

```
virtualenv apienv
```

Comment: No, still get: <blockquote>Reading package lists... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-virtualenv : Depends: python-pip-whl (>= 20.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
<blockquote>

Comment: @MikeGreer - ``sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`` first execute this command

Comment: @MikeGreer - if not try to remove the ``sudo apt-get remove python-pip-whl`` and excute the above commands

Comment: I'm just getting back to troubleshooting this today.  I think, that is think, I tried the 'setuptools' thing, but I will try again.  Yeah "python3-setuptools is already the newest version (45.2.0-1).
python3-setuptools set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded."

Comment: This answer doesn't address the actual question; OP wants `venv` (a Python "standard" module that's not available by default under Ubuntu), not `virtualenv`. Also, I would not use `apt` to update setuptools, i would use `pip`.

Comment: Your answer works for me, it deserves more points!

Answer (score 0):

the best way to create a virtual environment is either

### PIP

**pip3** is the `official package installer` for python3. It is always installed along with python interpreter. Install the `virtualenv(python2)` and `venv(python3)` package using pip3 and then using `venv` create your virtual environment in your preferred directory.

```
 
pip3 install venv
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

You can go through its [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for more  information.

### CONDA

**conda** provides a very easy method to create environments and install packages inside them.You can also install packages written in other languages like R through. conda creates an empty environment without python interpreter if required.
In **Windows**,open the Anaconda PowerShell Prompt and navigate to the folder where you want to use the environment. Run the following commands afterwards.

```
conda create -n test_env python==3.6.0
```

Here,

`test_env` is the name of the virtual environment

`python==3.6.0` is the package installed by conda in the newly created environment. If no version is specified then conda installs the latest version available.

Use the following command to activate your enviroment

```
conda activate test_env
```

Use the following command to activate your enviroment

```
conda deactivate
```

In **UNIX** systems you can access conda through the command-line interface directly.
The commands remain the same for creation of virtual environments.
You can further explore this here: [Managing environments with conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: This obviously is a tough nut to crack.  I'm beginning to think that the only solution is for me to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04.  Ooph!  Anyway, after trying "pip3 install venv"  I get an error telling me to update pip, and the command, which seems to work "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip"  But then, when I try "pip3 install venv" I get this error, "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement venv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for venv" .

Comment: Thank you, Anushka Gupta, I finally boned up and used Anaconda, and it works great for virtual environment.  To be honest, I think that Anaconda also straightened me up quite a but on the concept of virtual environments.  Now I have my head wrapped around what they're used for.  It helps me with PySimpleGUI projects.

Answer (score 0):

`apt list | grep venv` will give a list of the available Python packages that implement `venv`; there is `python3-venv` and then several version-specific flavors (`python3.8-venv`, `python3.10-venv`, etc).  One or more of these may display as "installed".

Where I am (stuck) on Ubuntu 18.04 (Python 3.6.9), on a freshly imaged system, I cannot issue `python -m venv ...` without an error.  I did not first capture the output of `apt list`, but I did `sudo apt install python3-venv` and I was subsequently able to create venvs.  After this, `apt list` shows `python3-venv` and `python3.6-venv` installed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, python was importing the `queue` package from the local directory instead of the system one.

```
  File "/tmp/tmphvbek7a8/pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/handlers.py", line 28, in <module>
    import queue
  File "${local_folder}/queue.py", line 3, in <module>
    from kafka import KafkaProducer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kafka'
```

Changing directory to the parent one and running `python3 -mvenv path_to_previous_diurectory/venv` worked.

I ran the "Failing command" reported in the OP to check this.