# How to fix broken installation of virtualwrapper in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, virtualenv

On Ubuntu 20.04.4 and python 3.8.10 my `virtualenvwrapper` installation is broken. When I try

```
mkvirtualenv  test
```

I get an error

```
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path
```

for some reasons I am unable to install `virtualenv` anymore, as I use

```
python -m venv myvenv
```

to create a virtualenv.

Is there some workaround? Maybe create an alias? Anything else?

In other words: How to make virtualenvwrapper work without `virtualenv` installed? (I am not able to install `virtualenv` to begin with. So please do not suggest to install that, as it does not work anymore).

Comment: Now this looks like something unlike the previous question. Ubuntu 20.04 should have python version **3.8.2**. AU is littered with questions from users that messed with the python version and ended up **reinstalling Ubuntu**. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232812/whats-the-default-python-version-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Maybe someone can create a tool that checks the whole setup and proposes how to fix it

Comment: For future reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417084/cannot-create-a-virtual-enviroment-with-python-3-8-10-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Can you detail how you installed `virtualenvwrapper` and/or `mkvenv`? I tried installing both with `pip install virtualenvwrapper` and `apt install virtualenvwrapper` and it works in both cases because both installation methods pull `virtualenv` as a dependency.

Comment: @roadmr Do you really think I write down every command I used to install a tool? I am trying now, but in most cases things don't work as they should be, and I use dozen of commands to install, uninstall, install it differently. I do NOT know how I installed things. I am pretty sure nobody will ever know how someone installed a tool like 2 years back....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's kind of tricky to get virtualenvwrapper installed without installing `virtualenv`; but by removing `virtualenv` selectively I was able to replicate your error. With `virtualenv` unavailable, this works to create virtual environments using `python3 -mvenv` instead of `virtualenv`.

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV='python3' VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='-mvenv' mkvirtualenv a-funny-name
```

Comment: But you didn't change the system's python version, did you?

Comment: I did not; used the version that comes with Ubuntu 20.04, which is 3.8.10. The same trick to set the VIRTUALENVWRAPPER variables would work for any version of Python you have installed as long as you point to the right python3 interpreter.